# What should the intermediate result that a fetch request returns be called? A blob or just response?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, frontend

when we use `fetch` in JS to issue a get request, we normally do thing like this

```js
fetch(endpoint).then(res => res.json()).then(result => ...)
```

However I was watching Wes Bos's JS 30 courses and he called the intermediate result that the fetch returns a `blob` as in

```js
fetch(endpoint).then(blob => blob.json()).then(result => ...)
```

I found the definition for blob here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

I am not knowledgable enough to judge if Wes Bos was using the right term here to refer to it as `blob` and I have no ways to contact him directly and ask him. Hope I can find some answers here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetch` returns a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object, not a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) - if you try to use blob methods like `.slice` and `.stream` on the result, errors will be thrown, since those methods do not exist.

```js
// Not OK:
fetch('data:,Hello%2C%20World!').then(blob => blob.slice()).catch((err) => console.log('err', err.message));
// OK:
fetch('data:,Hello%2C%20World!').then(res => res.text()).then(console.log);
```

Note that the Response *can* be converted into a Blob, but the return value from `fetch` would still be a Response:

```
fetch(endpoint)
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then((blob) => {
    // work with the blob here
  });
```

Calling the response a blob is incorrect. They're somewhat similar, but not the same. Better to avoid calling it a `blob` to avoid confusion.