# Design fetch with cache mechanism using SessionStorage: why does it converting the cached result to blob when making new response

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

https://www.sitepoint.com/cache-fetched-ajax-requests/

I am reading this article on making a fetch with SessionStorage as its cache. When the url is identical, we read from  SessionStorage to fulfill the request.

```js
const cachedFetch = (url, options) => {
  // Use the URL as the cache key to sessionStorage
  let cacheKey = url

  // START new cache HIT code
  let cached = sessionStorage.getItem(cacheKey)
  if (cached !== null) {
    // it was in sessionStorage! Yay!
    let response = new Response(new Blob([cached]))
    return Promise.resolve(response)
  }
  // END new cache HIT code

  return fetch(url, options).then(response => {
    // let's only store in cache if the content-type is
    // JSON or something non-binary
    if (response.status === 200) {
      let ct = response.headers.get('Content-Type')
      if (ct && (ct.match(/application\/json/i) || ct.match(/text\//i))) {
        // There is a .json() instead of .text() but
        // we're going to store it in sessionStorage as
        // string anyway
       // If we don't clone the response, it will be
        // consumed by the time it's returned. This
        // way we're being un-intrusive.
        response.clone().text().then(content => {
          sessionStorage.setItem(cacheKey, content)
        })
      }
    }
    return response
  })
}
```

What I don't understand is why do we need to do this in order to make a new response?

```js
    let response = new Response(new Blob([cached]))
```

I understand that sessionStorage only stores text, and I remember `blob` is more related to binary data like images/ videos/ audios. So why do we need to convert the text into blob first in order to make a new Response object.

I also asked a related question before [What should the intermediate result that a fetch request returns be called? A blob or just response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61035624/what-should-the-intermediate-result-that-a-fetch-request-returns-be-called-a-bl)
Essential it's about whether a response object is also a `blob` and the answer seems to be no

Comment: Because, as you say, the session storage only stores a textual representation, but the `Response` needs to contain arbitrary binary data?

Comment: Why Response has to contain binary data? I asked this question before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61035624/what-should-the-intermediate-result-that-a-fetch-request-returns-be-called-a-bl. People are saying Response object is not a Blob

Comment: A response object *is* not a blob, but can be thought to *contain* a blob. Otherwise how could you fetch a picture or a pdf file?

Comment: The `Response` constructor can also accept text, and since Session Storage can only store text, it wouldn't make any difference in this case. So I suppose the text data is being converted to Blog just by convention (or by copy-n-paste).